# Handle timeout in NodeMailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) (v1.0.4) to send emails in my Node application. Here is the code:

**smtpUtil.js**

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var config = require("../config").mailgun;

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Mailgun',
  auth: {
    user: config.username,
    pass: config.password
  },
});

transporter.mailSent = function(mailOptions, callback) {
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error in sending mail", error);
      callback(new Error(error));
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent successfully");
      callback();
    }
  });
}

module.exports = transporter;
```

I just include this `smtpUtil.js` in other files and then call `transporter.mailSent(mailOpts, callbackFn);` to send the email.

**My question is: how to add max timeout time & gracefully handle those in the process?**

The reason I am asking about above configuration is that recently in code, I invoked `transporter.mailSent(mailOpts, callbackFn)`. But due to some reason (possibly infinite timeout), the `callbackFn` was never triggered (neither success nor failure).

Latest [NodeMailer module](https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/setup-smtp/) though gives 3 timeout options, as follows:

- **options.connectionTimeout** how many milliseconds to wait for the
  connection to establish
- **options.greetingTimeout** how many milliseconds to wait for the greeting after connection is established
- **options.socketTimeout** how many milliseconds of inactivity to allow

But I am not sure which one would be relevant here to tackle the `callbackFn` never getting triggered issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a max TTL to process the email sending part.

Since I was using [kue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue), it was rather easy to configure a max [TTL](https://github.com/Automattic/kue#job-ttl).